# WebSocket issues with Sails.js on Heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I've recently been working on a project in Sails.js that makes use of websocket functionality. It is deployed on Heroku and it's been having issues with incoming connections being able to connect via websockets. I've tried forcing websockets client-side and server side, however Heroku just bounces every inbound request.

I've noticed in the heroku logs that nearly every transport method is polling, does anyone have any ideas on how I could get websocket support working?

Also does having an open polling connection does this eat up a significant amount of resources? I'm using redis to store sockets and sessions, if that offers any insight.